# can't connect to Mongodb Atlas even useUnifiedTopology: true,

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, mongodb-atlas

I am new to MongoDB. I am trying to connect mongodb atlas. I searched about it, most of the answers were to add `useUnifiedTopology: true,` however it didn't work. Here's my code to connect:

```
mongoose.connect(
  uri,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("the errors is", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Database connection successful");
    }
  }
);
```

**UPDATE**:I added my IP on google in the IP whitelist on mongodb atlas. It finally worked. However, obviously it needs the IP on google. Hhowever, it's changing with time. Is there a solution to it? Or do I just need to change the whitelist every time?

Comment: Have you configured your app? To the ip whitelist allowed to connect to your database replicas? https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist

Comment: thanks for your answer. No, doesn't ```useUnifiedTopology: true,``` solve this problem?

Comment: No. It does not. You have to configure your ip whitelist allowed to access your database instances.

Comment: I just did, I wrote my op on google, but still having the same error

Comment: Can you show how is the whitelist configured?

Comment: thank you for your reply. It finally worked. However, obviously it needs the ip on google. however, it's changing with time. is there a solution to it? or i just need to change the whitelist everytime?

Comment: if u IP keeps on changing it's best to allow access from anywhere. It anyways has a username/password protection. Otherwise, you will need static IPs

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the menu whitelist to allow access from ip address.
To do that:

1. Login to your account in mongodb atlas website
2. click `network access`
3. in tab `ip whitelist`, click `add ip address`

This image will show, so you can choose a rule to to whitelist your database replicas.

## If you would like to open access only for your current ip

Just click the button `add current ip address`

## If you would like to open access from everywhere for your database replicas there is an option.

You can just hit `allow access from anywhere`.

[image]

I would like to point out that this is a security flaw, and the risks you have, letting this option open.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply.yes, I got the security flow point, so what should id do other than this? isn't there a way to use the ip on my laptop rather that on google?

Comment: Yes there is, you can click in `add current ip address`. And it will get your current ip address

Comment: the problem is that I am working on this project with a team, I need all of them to access the data

Comment: Understand, but o do not know any solution to this. Sorry

Comment: Maybe you can try to open another question, explaining in detail this use case you have, and if anyone has a possible solution.